# php remove characters between and including specific characters

Tags: php, regex

I know how to remove specific character within a string but not sure about the following:

e.g. string: `Code [7845] [5589] [554] [4]`

I need to remove all instances of `[` and `]` and everything in between them, then trim whitespace off so I end up with simply: `Code`

Is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It is definitively possible and requires only a simple expression.

Answer (score 5):

This would do it :)

```
$result = preg_replace('/\[.*?\]|\s*/', '', $subject);
```

**Explanation:**

```
"
\[    # Match the character “[” literally
.     # Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *  # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\]    # Match the character “]” literally
"
```

As @Felix points out this is a fairly easy expression. You should take a look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and try to familiarize yourself with the various techniques you can use.

Comment: this will remove even this [12asda]. He asks only for numeric values :)

Comment: @SavasVedova Unless my Englsh betray me, *everything in between* means everything.

Comment: You'll encounter a problem with nested square brackets - See [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jHDTog)

Comment: @nickb I don't see any nesting in OP's example.

Comment: It's still _everything_ between the square brackets.

Comment: @nickb Well this is *simple* if the OP only wants a word which starts at the beginning...Otherwise chaos will occur.

Comment: @FailedDev what to adjust on the code if I don't want to remove all the spaces? thanx

Comment: @ivory-santos You need to remove the `|\s*` from the regex.

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
$str = trim(preg_replace('/\[\d+\]/', '', 'your_string_here'));
```

The first argument of the function is a regex. `\d` that you see matches a number, and the `+` following it says that you should match at least 1 number. [Check here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for more information on preg_replace. [Check here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html) for more information on Regex.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more details concerning your requirements.

Assuming:

```
$s = 'Code [7845] [5589] [554] [4]';
```

If the string always starts with what you're after and the rest can always be discarded, then this would probably be the most efficient:

```
$s = trim(substr($s, 0, strpos($s, '[')));
```

If you want to keep the original string and only remove groups of digits, then:

```
$s = trim(preg_replace('/\[\d+\]/', '', $s));
```